# Is $f(x) = x $ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

let  $X$  and $ Y$ be  two topological spaces .Given $X  =$ indiscrete topology and $Y = $discrete topology let  $f : X \rightarrow  Y$  be  a   function  .

Then  $f (x) = x $ is continuous . Yes/No

Im confusing that when $f$  will be  continuous ?

Comment: Did you try to use the definition of "continuous function" ?

Comment: @Peter if card $X = 1$ , the $ f $ will  be continious  as the discrete and indiscrete     coincide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define $f(x)=x$ then it means that $X\subseteq Y$. In your case there is no chance for $f$ to be continuous. If the topology on $X$ is not discrete then there is a subset $A\subseteq X$ which is not open in $X$. But $A$ must be open in $Y$ (since the topology on $Y$ is discrete), and if $f$ would be continuous then $A=f^{-1}(A)$ would be open in $X$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks u@Mark  but  if  $card X= 1$ , i thinks $ f $ will continious

Comment: If $|X|=1$ then the only topology which can be defined on $X$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: ohh  i got its @Mark  thanks u

Comment: So yes, obviously if $|X|=1$ then any function $f:X\to Y$ will be continuous, for any topological space $Y$.

Comment: It's also continuous when $|X|=0$, for the same reason: the discrete and indiscrete topologies on the empty set coincide.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=Y$. Since we view $X$ with regards to a not discret topology, there is a $U\subseteq X$ with $U$ is not open in $X$, but $U$ is open in $Y$, since the topology on $Y$ is the discret topology, which means that every subset is open.

So $f^{-1}(U)=U$ is not open. So $f$ is not continuous.